# Geo Targeting articles on a WordPress site

Tags: plugins, geo-data

I want to display the articles on my WordPress site depending on the **location of the User**. I am looking for a **country based** classification. Is there any already existing plugin that can help me with this?

I searched on the **WP site** but the **plugins** available there just **hide a small block of the article**. What I am looking for is a way to **hide the article completely from the user**.ie in the normal operation the post isn't visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WP Geolocation JS](http://www.wp-geolocation.com/install-setup)

and use JS or Shortcode to hide the content

Comment: ...And what Pritam said

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I tried GT-geo but it doesn't allow to hide the post completely.

Comment: ie. the link to the article is still on the home page

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this one?
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gt-geo-targeting/

Comment: Thanks for the help pritam.. Please read my above comment :)